# how to use the Pivoted Column values in Matrix use in another Tablix and write expressions on top of it

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services

I have one set of data with fields
StudentId, Name , Address in one dataset and being used in one Tablix.

also another set of data: StudentID Subject Marks in another Dataset and using Matrix to Pivot in the Report.

I am able to fetch  the Report in this way

**StudentID Name Address MAths Physcis Chemistry  Median**

1       Mike   NJ        85    70     90          2
2       David  CA        81    85     90          1

I was calculating Median by counting number of Subject Marks greater than 80.

Now how do I use the value of Median in Tablix instead of in Matrix.
Below should be the **expected output format**

**StudentID Median  Name Address MAths Physcis Chemistry**

1          2       Mike  NJ        85    70     90
2          3       David CA        81    85     90

**Note:** I am using Matrix to Pivot Subject Column in SSRS Report. I am using Pivot operation in SSRS instead of performing in SP because I get 40 columns after Pivoting in SP and need to physically map 40 columns. Here in example I have only given 3 columns(Maths, Physcis and Chemistry).

Also please do let me know if expected output format is at least possible.

Is there any way that I will be able to Pivot Subject Columns inside the Tablix itself instead of using the another Matrix??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to typically go about an aggregation like this. If you stick with the two existing datasets, you'll have to use the `Lookup` or `LookupSet` functions to get data from the other dataset. For example, if your table/matrix is using the second dataset as it's source, you would `Lookup` the Name of each student. Keep in mind that this is not efficient for large reports.

The other approach, which I would recommend, is to join these two datasets in SQL and use that as the data source for the report. This is more efficient and makes the report simpler to maintain.

It's good that you are letting the report do the pivoting for you, it works much better that way.

Comment: Is there any way that I will be able to Pivot Subject Columns inside the Tablix itself instead of using the Matrix??

Comment: In SSRS a table and matrix are the same thing. You can add whatever Row/Column groups you want to structure the pivot.